# How does the rails logger need to be setup to send emails for all errors and fatals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, logging

I can't seem to find how to setup rails 6 in a way that the logger sends an e-mail for all errors and fatal errors; i found loads of topics on how to customize the log messages themselves (and how to log emails that the app sends), but is there a way to connect actionmailer to the logger?

Thanks!

Comment: You would likely have to catch the error and then trigger the email.  What are you doing right now to catch the errors, can you share some code?

Comment: I'd look into AppSignal -- they make this trivial and have a wonderful reporting interface.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am looking into this and the gem below. I do not do anything particular to catch errors, but think of notifications if something goes horribly wrong.

Comment: ActionMailer is a relatively high level library which isn't ideal for error reporting as it may also crash. You're probally better off with one of the gems/services then reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using something like this gem https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification to log errors.

However, you could achieve what you're asking for with a custom logger

```
class MailerLogger < Logger
  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil)
    if severity == Logger::Severity::FATAL
      # Send email here
    end
    super(severity, message, progname)
  end
end

# config/application.rb or config/environments/production.rb

config.logger = MailerLogger.new(STDOUT)
```